# Identify 2x newish pieces please!

Tags: part-identification

I've got two pieces to identify, and I don't know how to look these ones up on Bricklink so am looking for help here:

[image: pieces]

- Light Bluish Grey 1x4 brick with a slot that a 2x2 round tile fits into
- Flat Silver round grenade-looking piece with bar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching for "1 x 4 shooter" yields part [16968 "Projectile Launcher, 1 x 4 with Inside Clips (Disk Shooter)"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=16968).

Paintstakingly looking through the list of all Flat Silver parts ultimately yielded part [40598c "Minifigure, Weapon Larger Blunt Grenade Tip"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=40598c).

(Finally, looking for sets which contain both parts yielded set [76150](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=76150-1))

Comment: Thank you very much! I did try to look for the 1x4 brick but I was using "slot" and "opening" instead. The grenade piece I didn't bother looking for at all because I didn't want to do what you did and look through all the pieces! Turns out we could have just went with my initial thought and typed "grenade" to find it instantly lol.